# How do I create a new row that sums up the previous rows?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

For the final output, I would like to have a table that has another row which is the total of my previous rows. I am a bit stuck. I have tried rollup function that I found on the internet but it doesn't seem to work for me.

So far I have for example:

[image: the results of the first table but I would like to have the final output of the second]

(the results of the first table but I would like to have the final output of the second)

In the image, I currently have the first table which I have selected the fields and made calculations which I wanted from a much larger table. But I now would like to use this first table that I have created above into the second. Creating a new row titled Total and summing up everything else. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `union all`:

```
select shop_id, subscription_plan, total_customer_a_b, tot_customer_yearly
from t
union all
select shop_id, 'total', sum(total_customer_a_b), sum(tot_customer_yearly)
from t
group by shop_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a common table expression (CTE) to reuse the calculation of totals in grand total like this:

```
with
aggregated_data as (
    -- your query that produces table 1
)
select *
from aggregated_data
union 
select 
 -- list of fields or simple text values and grand total as the sum
from aggregated_data
```

just make sure the 2 parts of the union have the same set of columns and data types

in that specific case the part below `union` would be something like

```
select 
 shop_id
,'Total' 
,sum(total_customer)
,sum(total_customer_yearly)
from aggregated_table
group by 1
```

Comment: would this still display the subscription plan and the previous rows of annual plan, monthly plan along with the total? Also what does group by 1 mean?

Comment: You have to try and you'll see. The rows above the total are returned by the part of the query that is above `union` when you just select from the subquery without summing. Group by 1 means group by shop_id (first column in the list). I assumed there might be different `shop_id`s where you'd like to get the totals